# Create a SQL Server full backup without affecting maintenance plan?

Tags: sql-server, backup, maintenance, snapshot, incremental-backup

We use a centralized SQL Server 2005 server for web development.  The server has a maintenance plan to take a full backup each Sunday and incremental backups on all other nights.  All databases use the Simple Recovery Model, so transaction logs are not a factor.

Additionally our programmers are asked to manually save a full backup whenever they make considerable changes to the database.  The full backup is checked in to our source control repository.

It occurs to me that a manual backup will affect the daily incremental backups done by the maintenance plan.  If I understand correctly, a programmer could take a manual full backup on Wednesday and the automated incremental on Thursday will be dependent on Wednesday's full backup instead of Sunday's.  Not good.

Is it possible to save a full backup that does not affect the maintenance plan?  My research suggests that a database snapshot might be appropriate, but I'm just looking for a backup without spawning a new database on the server.

We'll assume that the programmer can run/tailor a script if the functionality is not in SQL Management Studio.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they need to specify the copy_only option:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191495.aspx

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1075

This option is not available in the GUI interface, so the backup would have to be done from a script or query window.

Comment: Perfect!  Looks like I need to improve my Googling skills.  Thanks!